# Two "orocos kdl" packages

Tags: ros, orocos

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In `/opt/ros/groovy/share` there are two folders with near identical names: `orocos_kdl` and `orocos-kdl`.

`orocos_kdl` contains:
`cmake` and `package.xml`

`orocos-kdl` contains:
`orocos-kdl-config.cmake`

I'm not sure which I should use to install. I'm leaning towards `orocos_kdl` as it looks more like what I'd expect as I'm going through the catkin tutorials.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60243/two-%22orocos-kdl%22-packages/) by [loughnane](https://answers.ros.org/users/4638/loughnane/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-04-08**:
What do you mean by "use to install"? What are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Both folders you see result from the same source package, being orocos_kdl The orocos-kdl folder is the result of some legacy installation method from before the ROS era, if you are using ROS you should use the orocos_kdl folder since this is the name of the package. This discrepancy will be solved in hydro.

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Smits](https://answers.ros.org/users/350/ruben-smits/) with karma: 543 on 2013-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0